# Oracle: Table with: All Tables | All Columns | distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I am trying to create a select with 3 columns. It should store the table names in first column, the appropriate columns in the second column and the distinct values from the appropriate table/Column in the third one.

I succeeded the first to as you can see below but I am stuck in getting the appropriate third row.

Is anyone able to help me with that?

```
SELECT
    dba_tab_columns.table_name,
    dba_tab_columns.column_name
FROM
    dba_tab_columns 
JOIN 
    dba_tables on dba_tables.table_name = dba_tab_columns.table_name
```

Comment: What do you mean by distinct value from appropriate table/column? Do you mean all the values stored in all the columns of all tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a table name a dynamic variable in static sql so you can't get your 3rd column. You would need to generate the full sql dynamically, see here:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html
then execute the sql with something like sp_executesql. Though i realy don't see the point.